# Abbreviate "/home/user/file" to "~/file" in formatted fields (frame-title-format, etc.)

Tags: filenames, mode-line-format, frame-title-format

I have Emacs display the full path of the file in my window title:

```
(setq-default frame-title-format '("%f [%m] - Emacs"))
```

And in my mode-line:

```
(setq-default mode-line-buffer-identification
              (list 'buffer-file-name
                    (propertized-buffer-identification "%12f")
                    (propertized-buffer-identification "%12b")))
```

But I would prefer it to not show my actual user name, how can I get this abbreviate standard unix path?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use function `abbreviate-file-name`. `C-h f` tells us:

> `abbreviate-file-name` is a compiled Lisp function in `files.el`.
>
> `(abbreviate-file-name FILENAME)`
>
> Return a version of `FILENAME` shortened using `directory-abbrev-alist`.
>
> This also substitutes `~` for the user's home directory (unless the
> home directory is a root directory) and removes automounter prefixes
> (see the variable `automount-dir-prefix`).
>
> When this function is first called, it caches the user's home
> directory as a regexp in `abbreviated-home-dir`, and reuses it
> afterwards (so long as the home directory does not change;
> if you want to permanently change your home directory after having
> started Emacs, set `abbreviated-home-dir` to nil so it will be recalculated).

If you want to use that in `frame-title-format` and `mode-line-format`, try this:

```lisp
(setq-default frame-title-format
              '((:eval (list (abbreviate-file-name
                               (expand-file-name buffer-file-name))
                             " [%m] - Emacs"))))

(setq-default mode-line-buffer-identification
              '((:eval (list (abbreviate-file-name
                               (expand-file-name buffer-file-name))))))
```

Comment: Ah, but it won't work either in the frame title or in the mode-line... But it actually answers the question, so I'll upvote, and maybe re-phrase the title?

Comment: Updated. I didn't notice that you were actually asking two things.

Comment: You lose the "properties" (colors, but more seriously mouse interactions) but 1-I have a feeling we'll get there soon and 2-it *does* answer the question ; thanks!